# Prepending elements to ul with AJAX - REVISED

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a div with fixed size, and inside I have an unordered list (`<ul>`) of n elements.

When user scrolls up to the first element in that list, AJAX request goes to server to ask for more elements. Server responds with js that has n lines of

```
$('.entries').prepend('<li class="entry">some text</li>');
```

js successfully prepends elements, but they are on top of each other, they doesnt look the same as the old ones.

(For better understanding I am trying to do something that is in facebook inbox.)

When I inspect the code all `li` elements look the same (only different text), they all have the same css attributes, but the new ones (when looking preview) are on top of each other.

html

```
<ul class="entries">
    <li class="entry"> some text </li>
    <li class="entry"> some text </li>
    <li class="entry"> some text </li>
    <li class="entry"> some text </li>
    <li class="entry"> some text </li>
    <li class="entry"> some text </li>
    <li class="entry"> some text </li>
</ul>
```

js that is returned

`$('.entries').prepend('<li class="entry"> some text </li>');`

This is the picture that shows what happens.[image]

[This is the fiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS3LC/1/), the same thing I have on my page with difference that js that is executed here when user scrolls to the top is a response from ajax request.

and by the way, in that rails app

`<%= render entry %>`

generates text with some spaces around it (always the same amount) (i tried entry.text.strip)

and when that same code is executed not in html view, but in that js file before it sends it back there are no spaces

`$('.entries').prepend('<li class="entry"><%= j render entry %></li>');`

**_entry.html.erb**

```
<%= entry.text %>
<%= entry.date %>
```

**JS with AJAX request**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".entries").scrollTop($(".entries")[0].scrollHeight);
  return $(".entries").scroll(function() {
    var top;
    top = $(".entries").scrollTop();
    if (top < 0.05) {
      return $.getScript($('.pagination .next_page').attr('href'));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you using any UI frameworks? Just thinking that they may need to be informed of new content to mark-up the `li`'s. Not sure what else could be the issue if the fiddle is doing what you expect it to.

Comment: I use only jquery, bootstrap, but not here.
Fiddle is not using AJAX request, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Show some more of your jQuery code such as the aJax call and what it does.

Comment: I have added JS with AJAX request

Comment: I'm still unsure, how about adding the full thing to the fiddle as since it's a script it won't matter about cross-origin-request.

Comment: I tried my app without AJAX just prepend some random text and it still doesn't work. I think the problem could be with CSS